# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:edit distance between two strings is one

Tags: java, string, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to Check if edit distance between two strings is one

An edit between two strings is one of the following changes.

Add a character
Delete a character
Change a character

And I am facing "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException".

Do I need to check anything to prevent this exception in my code?

```
public class OneDiff { 
public OneDiff(String s,String s2){
int count=0;    
for (int i=0;i<(s.length()+s2.length());i++){
    if(s.charAt(i)!= s2.charAt(i)){
        count++;
            }
}
if(count==1){
    System.out.println("one difference");
}
}
public static void main(String args[]){
String s= "xxx";
String s1="xxxy";
OneDiff od=new OneDiff(s,s1);
}
}
```

Comment: Which statement throws the exception? What are the input strings?  Please visit the [help] and also read [ask].

Comment: `int length = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {` length is 0 your using `length-1` in for loop

Comment: Given length = 0, the for loop will not run.

Comment: Surprised, how and why is your code even getting executed. Your for loop and if statements won't be executed because of length initialized to zero

Answer (score 0):

As @Ramanlfc and @YoungHobbit explained, because your length is *0*, so it will throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

but for your calculation of string's distance, Your algorithm is wrong, you need to come true [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to calculate the string's edit distance.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<(s.length()+s2.length());i++){
```

`(s.length()+s2.length())` will take you beyond the length of either string and give a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to prevent the exception you will need to make sure that `i` is not bigger then any of the `String`s' length. You can do that by setting the loop to have only as many iterations as the length of the smallest `String`.

Here is an example:

```
for (int i=0;i<Math.min(s.length(),s2.length());i++){
    if(s.charAt(i)!= s2.charAt(i)){
        count++;
    }
}
```

And to account for the length difference, you can do this:

```
count += Math.abs(s.length() - s2.length());
```